# Jhipster - Newly created record not found

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jhipster, ehcache

I am working on an application where I need to create a record at the time of creating another, given certain conditions.

To do this, I use the proper repository and call the save method. The problem is that the newly created record is not displayed if I try to search it right away (findOne) unless I return all the records (findAll) first.

Follows the code snippet used.

```java
          request.setTable(restaurantTableRepository.findById(tableId).get());

            request.setWaiter(securityService.getCurrentLoggedInUser());

            request.setCashier(cashFlow.get().getCashier());

            request = requestRepository.saveAndFlush(request);

            subRequest.setRequest(request);
        }

        subRequest = subRequestRepository.save(subRequest);
        return subRequestMapper.toDto(subRequest);
```

When calling findOne passing the newly created request id, I get a 404 (record not found). If I call a findAll first, the registry is returned and after that findOne works too. Is it a cache problem?

Why doesn't findOne work at first?

Comment: Are u using any kind of hibernate cache?

Comment: Have you looked at Hibernate lazy-loading? Is your method transactional ? Is your DTO mapper coded tto include nested object?

Comment: What's the database? Everything is done in the same transaction?